# Sync a FTP folder locally

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, rsync, incremental-backup, synchronization

I have several images uploaded worth 1GB on the remote server that I want to download locally, but not continuously.

I tried using rsync reading its (excellent) man page but found repeated protocol issues and gave up. (There is some problem with rsync when bashrc is changed. I cant in good mind edit or change my bashrc just for this.)

What are the other alternatives to sync a folder unidirectional, but incremental.

FYFI, the following is the rsync command I used

```
rsync -e ssh -avz user_name@ftp.imcruis.in:chikmaglur-trip Desktop/Malnad2/
```

Comment: It's a bit hazy what exactly you mean with "continously" and "incremental".

Comment: And this didn't work because rsync didn't like your .bashrc??

Comment: Manni: Yes. Thats what I found by googling.

Comment: Maybe your question should be "How do I fix my problem with rsync?" Instead of "How do I find another tool besides rsync because I can't make rsync work?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could just work with wget --continue --mirror.

Comment: Exactly. But how. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

export RYSNC_RSH=ssh
rsync -avz user@:

If that does not work, what is the error you get?